# Beans.xml in maven

Tags: java

I am very new to maven, i am having a project which contains more than one service. Can we use multiple jaxws:endpoint in beans.xml.

For Example:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">

<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />

**<jaxws:endpoint id="accountSnapshot" implementor="AccountSnapshot" address="/AccountSnapshot" wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl/ser/service/rs/AccountSnapshot/1.0/AccountSnapshot.wsdl">

<jaxws:endpoint id="accountSnapshot1" implementor="AccountSnapshot1" address="/AccountSnapshot" wsdlLocation="classpath:wsdl/ser/service/rs/AccountSnapshot1/1.0/AccountSnapshot1.wsdl">**

        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="schema-validation-enabled" value="false" />
        </jaxws:properties>

</jaxws:endpoint>

</beans>
```

Comment: Maven? You should tag/retitle with Spring (I guess).

Comment: Are you getting any exception while trying to build using maven? what exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can of course have multiple jaxws:endpoint elements in beans.xml... but, as the comments suggest, this question has nothing to do with maven.